# ExtJS4 get a member of a store

Tags: javascript, extjs4

How can I get the element id of an item in a store range on ExtJS4 based on a property of the item? For instance, I am getting the store as follows:

```
var combobox = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('[xtype=mycombobox]')[0];
var items = combobox.getStore().getRange();
```

I want to jump to the correct item in the combobox based on a productid that a user selects elsewhere:

```
combobox.select(elementid);
```

I am just missing the logic that lets me say

```
elementid = items.getWhere('prodid', 'productid'); // Or however its actually done.
```

Comment: What ist your question? You asked already a similiar one. Normally you get a selected value from a combo and not a range of values. So how do you determine the value you are trying to fetch?

Comment: This is the closest method I could find to what I am trying to do: `combobox.getStore().findIndex('prodid',passedValue))` except that I get an error message that findIndex is not a method of getStore(). This is in a listener when a user types in a product id, I want to find out which element in the combobox store corresponds to that id so I can select it using combobox.select(). And in the future there are other ways I want to get the value such as from other controllers to basically pre-populate this pulldown item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I ended up coming up with, which actually required two seperate calls. Not sure if this is the most efficient way to do it but it seems to work.

First, I need to get the model that has a productid that equals value:

```
var model = combobox.getStore().findRecord('productId', value);
```

Then, I need to figure out what the index of that model is in the overall store:

```
var index = combobox.getStore().indexOf(model);
```

Then I can take the index and apply it to back to the combobox:

```
combobox.select(index);
```